# What are limitations for object recognition in ARKit2.0 in ios?

Tags: ios, 3d, arkit

I have already scanned a 3D object and saved ARReference object in Document directory. I am not getting what exactly affect on quick recognition of 3D object.

1. Does distance between camera and object matter while recognizing 3D object which has been already scanned and stored in document directory?
2. What parameters will affect on quick recognition of 3d object?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'not getting what exactly effect'?

I think the scan quality will definitely be one factor. Whether you scanned the whole object or just the frontal part, and how thoroughly you scanned and so on.

Also, the object detection is ARKit works for "static" objects unlike the image detection. Which means the object should not be in motion when being detected.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756950/what-are-limitations-for-scanning-and-detecting-3d-object-in-arkit2-0-in-ios/55757615#55757615) for further information to make your ARReferenceObject better.